# Unity - GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo () returns null after a scene is destroyed then reloaded

Tags: animation, controller, unity-game-engine, reload, scene

I am having an issue with the Unity animation controller. The controller is working when the scene is first loaded. The scene is destroyed and when loaded again I receive a NullReferenceException at:

(wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.Animator:GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo (int)

The animation controller appears to be present as the character I am controlling is in its default idle state and moving.

Comment: FIXED - We had a stray reference to the script object that was not being cleaned up. To avoid this use the OnDisable function and make sure that all references are removed.
   
    }